# How do I click on an element that appears sometimes 1 or sometimes 2 at different intervals

Tags: selenium

I have done this

```java
List<WebElement> element= driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
for(int i=0;element.size();i++)
{
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("")).isDisplayed();
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("")).click();
}
```

I am new to java and selenium , so I thought of doing this. Is this logic correct or am I wrong? If wrong(most probably) , can you please rectify and explain alongside , wud be very helpful.
I get element not interactable error on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "element that appears sometimes 1 or sometimes 2" ?

Comment: Do you mean sometimes appears some element and sometimes appears some other element and you want to click the element that appearing?

Comment: Also share the link if possible.

Comment: @Prophet actually it is a bug that throws up an error message when I load a page. So this message would appear within 5 secs of loading the page , then click ok . It might or might not appear 2nd time , 40% times , it does appear.  It could appear at 5 secs or even 10 secs after clicking ok.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for method to wait for one of two elements to appear and then to click on the appeared element you can use this method:

```java
public String waitForOneOfTwoElements(String xpath1, String xpath2){
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    try {     
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath1)),
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath2))));
        if(waitForElementToBeVisible(xpath1)){
            return xpath1;
        }else if(waitForElementToBeVisible(xpath2)){
            return xpath2;
        }
    }catch (Throwable t){
            return null;
    }
}
```

Where `waitForElementToBeVisible` is:

```java
public boolean waitForElementToBeVisible(String xpath) {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
            return true;
        }catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now, when you get the appeared element you can simply click it with:

```java
String appearedElementXpath = waitForOneOfTwoElements(xpath1,xpath2);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(appearedElementXpath)).click();
```